# Android MyView (FingerPaint Demo) Reset Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, view, reset

I have used the MyView class from the FingerPaint API DEMO (from [Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html)) and would like to be able to clear the view of any drawn lines. In effect resetting it to when it as first rendered on the start of the activity. My MyView view is declared in my XML layout (not programmed).

What's the simplest way of doing this with a button?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve this by modifying the MyView class as below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MyView extends View {

    private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
    private Paint   mPaint;
    private List<Path>  mPathsArray = new ArrayList<Path>();

    public MyView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF00F1F5);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);

        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }
    public void clear(){
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mPath = new Path();
        invalidate();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }
    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPathsArray.add(mPath);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Just incase other people want to achieve the same effect.